# How do you get the "Running the Show" Achievement?

Tags: achievements, dirt-showdown

> **Running the Show**
>   Dominate a friend in Challenge mode

How do you actually dominate a friend in challenge mode? I have beaten some challenges, but did not get this achievement yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to win 10 challenges in a row to unlock this achievement. You can do this by either beating the best scores of your friend or by beating 10 challenges sent by him. [Source](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/dirt-showdown/guide/)